# UITest on Xamarin Forms writing StyleId as Label rather than ID

Tags: xamarin.forms, uitest

I'm trying to set up a UI Test on a Xamarin Forms Projects

I followed the guide [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/uitest-and-test-cloud/) and added StyleId to my username control

```
<Entry x:Name="username_name" 
        StyleId="username_styleid"
        Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBoolConverter}}"
        Style="{StaticResource TextboxLight}"
        Placeholder="{Binding UsernameLabel}" />
```

I added code into the Android MainActivity

```
Forms.ViewInitialized += (sender, e) => {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.View.StyleId))
    {
        e.NativeView.ContentDescription = e.View.StyleId;
    }
};
```

When I run the test and use REPL, I can see that the StyleId has been output as a label property rather than an id property

[image]

Has anyone managed to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is working as designed. On iOS you will see the value show up as `id`; on Android it will show up as `label`.

`app.Query(c=>c.Marked("username_styleid"))` will work across platforms. The shorter form of `app.Query("username_styleid")` does the same thing.

`Marked` will find the element(s) with the specified value in the `id` field on iOS; the `label` field on Android and as `text` on either. So, a key to making this easy and useful in writing your tests is to make the StyleID (or AutomationId) different than text that appears in your app.

Comment: Thanks Glen. I was beginning to realise this but its nice to have it confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

Using the StyleId will soon be obsolete with 2.2.0.

I haven't personally tested it yet but

> **AutomationId Support**
>
> Xamarin.Forms now has first class support for setting automation
>   identifiers for usage with Xamarin UITest or other testing frameworks.
>   Simply setting the AutomationID property should allow the automation
>   framework to find and interact with your controls.

Not sure what an AutomationId translates to however, hopefully an ID.

Comment: Thanks Adam, great news. I hope it works well as we have a load of UI Tests to write.

Comment: Just had a play with 2.2.04-pre2 and the new AutomationId property. Unfortunately it still outputs it as a label, not an id

Comment: Good to see it confirmed above. I was about to just double check but I had a feeling it was meant to be label.